# Dynamic Menu Navigation In Umbraco Using .Net User Control

Tags: menu, navigation, umbraco

I am .Net developer and am looking for example related to creation of dynamic navigation menu in umbraco 7 using .Net user control without using MVC technique and XSLT. I have searched it on google but got not much response on it, examples which i got were using either XSLT or Razor. I have not any experience in MVC and XSLT and looking for technique related to using classic ASP.Net, i.e. without using XSLT and MVC.  It will a great help if any one could please provide some useful videos or links with examples which i could refer to.

Thanks

Tarunjit Singh

Answer (score 2):

You should *really* look into the Razor thing.  It just TOO simple not to try!
It looks like c# mixed with some HTML.  If you really want to stick to .Net UserControls you might miss out on future versions.

Creating navigation in a usercontrol is very difficult because you have 2 options

1. you need to write out HTML yourself
2. create some custom model to some 3th party control

Both of these options will never return the **exact** html as you wanted.  Razor (and xslt) on the other hand will.

If you still want try something in a .Net User control anyway, get an instance of the Umbraco Nodes you want.  Let's give an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Umbraco.Web;

public partial class UserControls_TestUserControl : UmbracoUserControl
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var cache = this.UmbracoContext.ContentCache;
    var rootNodes = cache.GetAtRoot().First().Children;
    foreach (var node in rootNodes)
    {
      Response.Write("<li>" + node.Name + "</li>");
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to call this code, don't forget to add a macro, and insert the macro in your template.

Just in case you would like to explore razor, here is an equivalent:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
  var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1);
  var menuItems = homePage.Children;
}
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

    @foreach (var item in menuItems)
    {
        <li><a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a></li>
    }
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This example can be used as a partial view.  And can be put in your (Razor) template using: `@Html.Partial("NameOfThePartial")`

You have to admit, it's not too hard.